# Jupyter: XSRF cookie does not match POST

Tags: docker, csrf, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to transfer files using a python program running on a local Anaconda to a local Jupyter within a docker container using the Jupyter rest API.

I managed already to execute a `requests.get()` successfully after muddling-through a bit on how to input the token.

Now I would like now to execute a `requests.post()` command to transfer the files.

Configuration:

1. local docker container running on docker toolbox for windows

- docker version 17.04.0-ce, build 4845c56
- tensorflow/tensorflow incl. Jupyter latest version install
- jupyter_kernel_gateway==0.3.1

2. local Anaconda v. 4.3.14 running on a Windows 10 machine

Code:

```
token = token_code_provided_by_jupyter_at_startup
api_url = "http://192.168.99.100:8888/api/contents"
# getting the file's data from disk and converting into a json file
cwd = os.getcwd()
file_location = cwd+r'\Resources\Test\test_post.py'
payload = open(file_location, 'r').read()
b64payload = base64.encodestring(payload)
body = json.dumps({
            'content':b64payload,
            'name': 'test_post.py',
            'path': '/api/contents/',
            'format': 'base64',
            'type':'file'
        })
# getting the xsrf cookie
client = requests.session()
client.get('http://192.168.99.100:8888/')
csrftoken = client.cookies['_xsrf']
headers ={'Content-type': 'application/json', 'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken, 'Referer':'http://192.168.99.100:8888/api/contents', 'token':token}
response = requests.post(api_url, data=body, headers=headers, verify=True)
```

Error returned

> ```
> [W 12:22:36.710 NotebookApp] 403 POST /api/contents (192.168.99.1): XSRF cookie does not match POST argument
> [W 12:22:36.713 NotebookApp] 403 POST /api/contents (192.168.99.1) 4.17ms referer=`http://192.168.99.100:8888/api/contents
> ```

Answer (score 6):

My solution is inspired by @SaintNazaire. In my Chrome browser, I opened the cookie folder and found the repeated `_xsrf` items in Cookies. I removed all of them and refreshed the Jupyter, and then everything went well.
[image]

Comment: Thanks. this worked for me. I'm wondering if this is a reliable solution for the long-term. is there any other solution?

Comment: @bpfrd I am not sure... but the issue doesn't happen anymore at least for me

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no need for xsrf cookie when using header token for authentification.

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'token ' + token}
```

Reference is made to the Jupyter notebook documentation.

http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html

Answer (score -1):

Simply go to your chrome or default browser setting using the jupyter notebook. Change the cookie setting to allow third party cookies. I think this will solve your problem.